# Is there a way to make matlab gridlines bold?

Tags: matlab, grid, matlab-figure

I know that I can set the color of gridlines using:

```
pax = gca;
pax.GridColor = 'black';
```

But the gridlines are still a faint grey. I would like to make them darker. Is there a way to make the gridlines bold?

*Note I do not want to make the gridlines thicker, I just want to make them darker that the faint grey that seems to be the automatic when using black*

I am using polar plots and when I print them, the grids are almost too faint to see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to modify the [`GridAlpha`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_GridAlpha) property as well so that the grid lines are actually opaque. The default value is `0.15` so even though they are black they appear gray since they are transparent. You'll want to use a `GridAlpha` value of `1` .

```
pax.GridAlpha = 1
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks!! this is right. It won't let me accept your answer? Says I have to wait like 10 minutes.